# After Uploading an image to the server, how do i return the database ID for that Image

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In ASP.net if you upload a file using a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest there doesn't seem to be a way of returning a value (for example the ID from the database). I've looked into Ajax calls to pass files as a binary data because this is the only way that seems to allow me to return a value, but wasn't sure if this is the best way to do it.

what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest has a responseText function that can be populated using this serverside code:

```
Response.Write("your ID")
Response.End()
```